Certifications/diplomas/licenses required for a freight forwarder to contract directly with airlines/shipping lines for independent freight booking
I’m a freight forwarder looking to expand my operations to book air and ocean freight directly with airlines and shipping lines. I’d like to understand the specific certifications, diplomas, or licenses that are generally required to sign contracts with these carriers and operate as their direct customer.
For example, I know that IATA accreditation is essential for working with airlines, and FMC licensing is necessary for NVOCC operations in the U.S. However, I’m unsure if additional certifications are needed for other regions or specific requirements related to handling different types of cargo (e.g., dangerous goods).
Could someone provide guidance on the mandatory and recommended qualifications for both air and ocean freight? I’m especially interested in any requirements for:

Direct contracting with airlines and shipping lines
Issuing House Bills of Lading
Cargo loading and security standards

Thanks in advance for any advice or insights on establishing these credentials to operate independently!

Welcome to Aviation.SE.  Unfortunately, this question is beyond the scope of what is discussed and considered as "on topic" here.

@mins I'm willing to go with whatever the community decides.
